Google Cloud will soon be sponsoring Information Security Stack Exchange
Update December 23rd, 2024
The site sponsorship has been extended through March 31st, 2025.

Update September 20th, 2024
The site sponsorship has been extended through December 31st.

We're excited to announce that Google Cloud will be sponsoring Information Security Stack Exchange beginning July 8th through December 31st. We wanted to give you a heads-up and walk you through what it will look like.
How and where will the sponsorship be displayed?
For users in the US and Canada, the sponsorship will be visible on the right side of the header at the top of the site in a manner that's similar to the mockup below:

What else changes?
Nothing! Quoting from the original MSE announcement on sponsorships:
First — sponsors do not own these Q&A sites. Sponsors work alongside our communities who ultimately build these sites. Communities ask the questions; communities create the tags; communities conduct elections as they do now, and we are not renaming our current sites like a garish sport stadium to the highest bidder. Any ads a sponsor submits still have go through our crazy-strict ad editorial process… as it has always been. Companies do not have access to personal data, and all Q&A content remains irrevocably licensed under Creative Commons for sharing and attribution.
Sponsorships are a tool that our clients can use to let folks who would be interested in their products know about them.
What if I think I've found a design glitch/bug?
If something looks off, please report it as a bug so we can investigate and squash it.
That's it. If you have any other questions or concerns, please leave them as answers below.
Also, thank you. These types of partnerships help us bring more resources to our communities, and they wouldn't be possible without the work you've put into making Information Security Stack Exchange successful.

"July 8th through September 30th" stupid question, shouldn't that be around…now? Can't seem to find any difference in the banner.

@MarcusMüller Not a stupid question. It only shows on the main site, not the meta.

https://imgur.com/a/dXtzHE1 <— same picture with and without ad blockers active, firefox on Linux

@MarcusMüller Hmm weird. I don't have any issue seeing it. I will flag this as a possible bug. Thank you.
